# stripe popup just to create token

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to use the stripe modal popup to simply gather billing information and create the token?  For example, there would be a detailed form with about 20-25 questions, payment at the end and instead of having fields to fillout - I wanted to use the stripe popup to gather information and make token - but I do not want it to submit. Is this possible and if so does someone have a jsfiddle example?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "[custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom)" to do this. The `token` callback function you set up will receive the token, and afterwards it's up to you to do whatever you want with it.